# Session need to login all the time in android browser

Tags: php, session

I have an admin session php that lose session values all the time in the Android Chrome Browser (It works ok on desktop browser).

Sometimes I need to login for about 10 times to do a work.

**my login.php:**

```
// if password ok
session_name(md5('seg'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']));
session_start();

$_SESSION["id"]     = $id;
$_SESSION["user"]   = $user;
```

**admin index.php:**

```
session_name(md5('seg'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']));
session_start();

    if(empty($_SESSION["id"]) || empty($_SESSION["user"]))
    {
        header("Location:logout.php"); // IT COMES HERE ALL THE TIME
        die();
    }

session_write_close();
```

Why does it work on the desktop, but not on the mobile browser?

---> edit

it is perfect on android firefox. but not android chrome.

Comment: Try to remove the `session_name` call and see if it's ok..

Comment: @MateiMihai same thing.